# uploading application in google play in apk file exeed 50 MB?

Tags: java, android

i upload my application in android market.i have an problem my apk file exceed 50 MB.in developer console to download expansion file. what is this? how to download? otherwise how to compress my apk as 50 MB. help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read through the Android Developer's [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html) page?
It contains great instructions on how to use expansion files.

It's difficult to give tips on how to best utilize the expansion files or on how to decrease the size of your APK without knowing more about your application. In general, I would say the easiest way to decrease the size of your APK would be to move resources (especially any large ones you may have, such as videos) to an expansion file.

You should also check to make sure that you don't have any unused or unwanted resources in your APK, such as the Play store promotional graphics for your app.

Comment: above 50MB apk file does not upload? my apk file is 60 MB

Comment: 50MB is the maximum APK file size, so no, a 60MB APK file will not upload. You need to either move some of your resources to an expansion file, or you need to find another way to get your APK under 50MB.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to override this. You are now allowed to upload two additional resource files that have a limit of 2gb *each*. So, you can add/move up to 4gb of extra resources (in your case move).
You can read more about this [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html) (android-developers blogspot).

edit: Tanis.7x had a more useful link.

Comment: above 50MB apk file does not upload? my apk file is 60 MB.

Comment: @J.R.P I haven't tried myself, but since there's an explicit limit set to 50mb I can't imagine that it's possible. Move some resources to a separate file. Example of resources: images, videos, text documents etc.).

Comment: Just now i try to upload my android apps 58MB( have includes 52MB of mp3 files and remaining 6MB source code and logic). But i am unable to upload 58 MB. It requires Expansion file to upload if apps is above 50 MB. Even though i walk through all the expansion guides i have no idea to step forward. Please guys help me. Please give details steps based on my above mentioned application.

Comment: @J.R.P If you tell us more about what kind of application you have we'll be able to help you. I'm guessing your application isn't all code (text) since it's that big. You might need to move all menu, button and background (all layout) images.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer, but it may help others who encounter a similar issue:

**As of recently** (Sept. 2015)**, you are able to upload APKs up to 100 MB** if you are targeting Android 2.3 and above - you can read more about it [on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en-GB). This limit used to be 50 MB before. There is also the Android developers blogspot article explaining the changes [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html).

Alternatively, or if your app exceeds the 100 MB APK limit, you can use **expansion files**. These are additional files that are downloaded after your app has installed and can be up to 4 GB (to be specific, you can have two expansion files of up to 2 GB each). You can learn more about expansion files on [this page on the Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).